# Getting the source code out of SAP

Tags: software-development, sap-netweaver, abap

SAP stores the source code in internal databases. For some analytics and faster code search (`CODE_SCANNER` sometimes is too slow), I'm looking for a tool, plugin or macro that could get the [ABAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABAP) source code out of SAP and store it in local files on my PC.

Such a tool must

- support ABAP
- work with SAP 7.40
- cost less than 30 USD / 30 EUR
- save as plain text, UTF-8 or UTF-16 files

Ideally it also

- exports historical data (not sure in what format one would export this)

It needn't

- provide search capabilities, I'll use Agent Ransack
- provide statistics, I'll look for a separate tool
- export other development objects such as tables
- support Java, since we don't have that

Comment: Can I add a __really__ nice to have: Full round trip - i.e. Import to SAP as well as Export - this would allow storing the source code in a non-SAP version control system such as git.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: of course you can - although I don't need it. I "only" work in QA, I don't contribute to SAP development. I'm still interested in some metrics, e.g. how much of the code base has changed. If you add that feature, it should be "safe" and not push my changes into SAP without notifying me.